# javascript getElementById is null - Id passed by this

Tags: javascript, html

Maybe I'm not using 'this' right.

HTML:

```
<div style="margin: 4px; padding: 10px; border: solid 1px;" onmouseover="darken(this);">
```

JavaScript:

```
function darken(elt) {
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById(elt.id).style.backgroundColor = "#e8e8e8";
}
```

?

Comment: If you have `this` that refers to the `<div>` why to search for it by ID? `elt` **is** that element already.

Comment: HTML belongs in `.html` files, CSS belongs in `.css` files, and JS belongs in `.js` files. Keep JS and CSS out of your HTML attributes, because they don't belong there.

Comment: You didn't specify an Id for this element

Comment: @zzzzBov that's a big generalization. I'd add that script and style blocks can be appropriate too.

Comment: @RickViscomi, `<link href>` and `<script src>` are fine, but anything else should be avoided.

Comment: @zzzzBov without getting into a religious debate, I'd say that it can sometimes be faster to load styles or scripts with `<style>` or `<script>` than to incur an additional HTTP request. Some performance analysis tools explicitly recommend this technique.

Comment: There are n number of these elements created dynamically.  I went with the suggestion of not using getElementById at all, since I was passing in the element.  Seemed like the best answer to me.

Comment: @RickViscomi, agreed, which is why I said "avoided". There are certainly exceptions to the rule, but they should be carefully analyzed to be certain that they're necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is a reference to the element. You could simply use it as:

```
function darken(elt) {
    elt.style.backgroundColor = '#e8e8e8';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a reference to the element, there's no need to lookup its ID then query the document for the element matching that ID. (There is no ID assigned to that element by the way).

Answer (score 3):

### ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Zw5Mm/)***

The first issue is that there is no `id` on that element so you cannot use `document.getElementById` to find it.

An advantage that you can use is that you already passed the element with `this`:

```
function darken(elt) {
 "use strict";
 elt.style.backgroundColor = "#e8e8e8";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You havn't provided any `Id` to your div element

```
<div id="myDiv" style="margin: 4px; padding: 10px; border: solid 1px;" onmouseover="darken(this);">
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ygQfX/)